# Is it possible to mix OpenFL with NME?

Tags: haxe, nme, openfl

OpenFL is great, but the [latest version of NME](http://gamehaxe.com/2014/03/06/nme-5-0-rereleased/) supports `StageVideo`.

So is it possible to build a project with OpenFL and include some NME libraries to be able use `StageVideo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really all you would need to do is, in your Project.XML file, include:

```
<haxelib name="openfl" />
<haxelib name="nme" />
```

Assuming, of course, that you have both installed via haxelib. Then you could call either/both libraries.